# How to hide a lookup value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dynamics-crm

really struggling here,

I have a Dynamics look up value, I want to hide it onload, not sure how to do this, my code is below:

```
<div id="id-915f6055-2e07-4276-ae08-2b96c8d02c57-7-0bd3db-d9af-4782-9025-509e298dec-LookupResultsDropdelected_tag_text_0" 
title="Dace &amp; advice" 
data-id="category.fieldControl-LookupResultsDropdown_category_selected_tag_text" 
role="presentation" class="pa-au pa-at ">Dance &amp; advice</div>
```

Whats the JavaScript code for this, currently trying something like

```
formContext.getControl("field_1").removeOption(Dace &amp; advice);
```

Please advise, perhaps how to hide by title or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Dynamics (you didn't write the exact version and this is important at some point) forms are created/updated using the Form Designer. If you need to always hide that lookup from the form you can go inside the Form Designer and hide or remove the related field.

If you need to hide the lookup based on certain conditions in the OnLoad event, then you need to use JavaScript. You can google if you need help on how to add a JavaScript function to a Dynamics form.

The correct syntax to hide a field is

1. to find the logical name of the field (for example `accountid`)
2. use the `setVisible` method from `getControl`, based on your Dynamics version can be

for version prior to 9.0

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("accountid").setVisible(false);
```

for version on or after 9.0

```
formContext.getControl("accountid").setVisible(false);
```

but `formContext` obtained by `executionContext` (and passed when you add the function handler inside the Form designer), like this sample:

```
function myFunction(executionContext)
{
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
```